# Is there a shorter or more trivial way to prove that $ x > \cos (x)-\cos (2 x) $ holds for all $x>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I want to prove that the inequality

$$ x > \cos (x)-\cos (2 x)  $$

holds for all $x>0$.

**My attempt:**
Since the function on the RHS is periodic, we can find the position of extrema (on first period $2\pi$) by computing the first derivative; comparing them with the function $x$ which is increasing, we can prove that it holds.

[image]

**Question**
Is there a shorter or more trivial/obvious way to prove this?

Comment: $$\begin{align}\cos(x)-\cos(2x)&=1+\cos(x)-2\cos^2(x)\\&=\frac{9}{8}-2\left(\cos(x)-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\end{align}$$Not sure how this helps though.

Comment: More generally, by the same argument given in Misha Lavrov's answer, $$|\cos x - \cos y| < |x - y|$$ for all distinct real $x, y.$ See, for example (there are many near-duplicates) [Is there anyway to show $\left| {\frac{{\cos x - \cos y}}{{x - y}}} \right| \le 1$ other than taking derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1356682)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be seen geometrically.

Let $P = (\cos x, \sin x)$ and $Q = (\cos 2x, \sin 2x)$; then arc $PQ$ on the unit circle has length $x$. Its projection onto the horizontal axis is an interval containing both $\cos x$ and $\cos 2x$, and the length of that projection is always smaller, because arc $PQ$ is not perfectly horizontal and flat. Therefore
$$
    x > |{\cos x - \cos 2x}|
$$
for all $x>0$, which implies the inequality we want.

Comment: Thanks. But this looks longer that the first derivative test I mentioned in the text. I thought maybe there is an obvious way of which I am not aware of.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to just say "it's obvious if you look at the picture", so I took my time explaining it. But I think this is much less work than taking derivatives.

Comment: (The critical points of $x - \cos x + \cos 2x$ are actually rather obnoxious! There's one where $x \approx 0.376503$ which is the arctan of a root of a cubic polynomial. By any chance, is your first derivative test comparing the maxima of $\cos  x - \cos 2x$ to $x$? That is much simpler, but is not actually guaranteed to work!)

Comment: We can also return to algebra when $\frac\pi 2 < x \le 2$ since then $\cos x <0$ and thus $\cos x - \cos 2x < 1 < x$ (and of course $\cos x - \cos 2x \le 2$ always)

Comment: There's now a simpler argument which does not need to consider various cases for $x$.

Answer (score 5):

If $x>2$, the statement is trivial. For $0<x\leq 2,$ one has $$x>2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\geq 2\sin\left(\frac{3x}2\right)\sin\left(\frac x2\right)=\cos(x)-\cos(2x).$$

Comment: You need to split into two cases. $2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\geq 2\sin\left(\frac{3x}2\right)\sin\left(\frac x2\right)$ is not true for e.g. $x = 5\pi/2$ (LHS < 0, RHS > 0).

Comment: You’re right. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

*Almost solution.*
Mean value theorem.  Note $\cos' = -\sin$.  For $x>0$ we have $ 0 < x < 2x$ and
$$
\frac{\cos(2x) - \cos(x)}{2x-x} = -\sin(\xi)
$$
for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $2x$.  Thus
$$
\frac{\cos(2x) - \cos(x)}{x} \le 1
\quad\text{so}\quad
\cos(2x)-\cos(x) \le x .
$$
Why can we not have equality?  For example, $\xi = 3\pi/2$?

Comment: Intuitively, we can rule out equality when $x \ne 0$ because $\frac{\cos 2x - \cos x}{2x - x}$ is the *average* rate of change on $[x,2x]$. The *maximum* rate of change at isolated points in that interval could be as high as $1$, but it's less than $1$ at most points, so the average should also be less than $1$. Making this rigorous feels annoying, but it should be possible.

Comment: Here's a thought: chop $[x,2x]$ into $k$ intervals $[x_0, x_1] \cup [x_1, x_2] \cup \dots \cup [x_{k-1}, x_k]$, where at least one interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ does not contain a point $\xi$ where $\sin \xi = -1$. Then $\frac{\cos 2x - \cos x}{2x - x}$ is a weighted average of $\frac{\cos x_1 - \cos x_0}{x_1 - x_0}, \dots, \frac{\cos x_k - \cos x_{k-1}}{x_k - x_{k-1}}$, all of these are at most $1$, and the $i^{\text{th}}$ one is strictly less than $1$.

Comment: @GEdgar Why you have used the phrase "almost solution"? I am not a mathematician, and to me, your answer seems perfect (short and simple).

Comment: @sara96 ...  The problem says "$\lt$".  This proof only shows "$\le$". Misha's comments show us how to close the gap.

Answer (score 3):

For $x > 0$ is
$$
 \cos(x)-\cos(2x) = \int_x^{2x} \sin(t) \, dt < \int_x^{2x} 1 \, dt  = x \, .
$$
Strict inequality between the integrals holds because $\sin(t) < 1$ for “almost all” $t$.

Comment: Thanks. You did not consider the equality sign since; did you assume $t\neq0$? What does "almost all" means here?

Comment: @sara96: $1-\sin(t)$ is strictly positive except for the points $t=\pi/2+2k\pi i$, that is sufficient to conclude that $\int_a^b (1-\sin(t)) \, dt > 0$ for any $a < b$. Therefore is $\int_x^{2x} \sin(t) \, dt < \int_x^{2x} 1 \, dt$ with strict inequality.

Comment: Correction: It should be “except for the points $t = \pi/2 + 2k \pi$” and $k$ runs through the integers.